# JPOS unpacking running example

Tags: iso8583, jpos

I'm trying to use the JPOS library to pack/unpack ISO8583-1987 messages.

I have a problem with the format, and i can't find any running example on the internet.

Could someone give me a running example of Unpacking a hexadecimal message, because there is a lot of examples with ASCII message, but this is not what i need.

Thank you all for your time & attention

Julien

Comment: I don't know if jpos has a method to unpack from a hexadecimal string message, but you could easely write some method `hexaStringToAscci` I could help you with that if each byte is represented by two hexadecimal characters.

Comment: Hello !!! The problem i think is that all the fields are in different formats, some are in char, other are numbers, other are bitmap values, i don't think you can convert all the fields in ASCII value

Comment: Yes, you are right. You can transform your "hexa string" to byte[] decimal array, then you can "unpack" with this value. If you want i could answer with an example of this transformation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have the hex string representing the message in a String, in that case you have to convert it into a byte array.

For example assuming you have the string as an argument to your main. Anyhow you have to know the format of the iso message contained in that hex representation. For example if the message is binary you have to choose ISO87BPackager, if it is ascii you have to choose ISO87APackager.

```
import org.jpos.iso.packager.ISO87BPackager;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOException;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOUtil;

public class ParseISOMsg {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ISOException {
        String hexmsg = args[0];
        // convert hex string to byte array
        byte[] bmsg =ISOUtil.hex2byte(hexmsg);
        ISOMsg m = new ISOMsg();
        // set packager, change ISO87BPackager for the matching one.
        m.setPackager(new ISO87BPackager());
        //unpack the message using the packager
        m.unpack(bmsg);
        //dump the message to standar output
        m.dump(System.out, "");
    }
}
```

For example if you call `java -cp .:jpos.jar ParseISOMsg 080000200000008000001234563132333435363738` it should print:

```
<isomsg>
    <!-- org.jpos.iso.packager.ISO87BPackager -->
    <field id="0" value="0800"/>
    <field id="11" value="123456"/>
    <field id="41" value="12345678"/>
</isomsg>
```